# EdgeView2 SDK for Rad Studio

Tags: delphi, microsoft-edge, rad, rad-studio

I'm using Rad Studio 11 and can't download EdgeView2 SDK, it gives an error: interal check error. Can anyone give a direct link to download the SDK or the WebView2Loader.dll file?

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Google/Bing/Whatever is your friend. Easy to find at Microsoft website.

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component#Manually_Installing_the_Edge_WebView2_package_from_NuGet and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/ and also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution

Answer (score 1):

**Dear friend,**

The link you need to download the official WebView2Loader.dll libraries for both 32bit and 64bit is as follows:

**https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/**

Once on this page you can select the following action:
--- Open in NuGet Package Explorer

Then you will see both libraries inside the following directories, if we talk for example about Windows development:

Runtimes\winx-64\native\WebView2Loader.dll

Runtimes\winx-86\native\WebView2Loader.dll

[image: Location view]

In order to use TwebBrowser in Edge mode, you must include the WebView2Loader.dll library (32 or 64 as needed) in the directory where your application executable is located.